# Which Hoshana teffilot and Musaf Korbonos go with which days in Israel?‎

Tags: tefilla, eretz-yisrael, shacharis-morning-prayer, sukkot, chagim-holidays

I have an Artscroll siddur which lists the different Hoshanos to say on which days of Chol Hamoed
Sukkos in America,‎ and also in the Musaf which korbonos to say for each day,‎ but it seems to be counting the days of Chol Hamoed starting after two days of Yom Tov as is kept in America, but I am wondering if Chol Hamoed starting a day earlier in Israel affects which Hoshanos and Korbonos in Musaf are said.

For instance,‎ it lists the Hoshanas for this year as beginning on Monday
with אערוך שועי,‎ then on Tuesday אבן שתיה,‎ then Wednesday אל למושעות,‎ and Thursday אדון המושיע,‎ but there must have been something for Sunday in Israel.‎

‎Korbonos in Musaf for the first day of Chol Hamoed are listed as beginning וביום השני.‎

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The *musaf korbanot* are much simpler in Israel. Just say that day’s passage: on the second day of the festival (first day *chol hamoed* in Israel) say וביום השני, on the third day say וביום השלישי etc., as opposed to in *chutz la’aretz*  where on the third day of the festival one says both וביום השני and וביום השלישי.

*Hoshanot* are the same as that being said on that day in *chutz la’aretz*.

For the first day *chol hamoed* in Israel, say what is listed for the second day of *yom tov* in *chutz la’aretz* (this year *lema’an amitach*).

For second day *chol hamoed* in Israel (third day of the festival), say what the Artscroll has as for the first day *chol hamoed* (this year *e’eroch shu’i*).

As noted by Double AA in a comment, there is room to argue that in Israel a different order of *hoshanot* should be used than in *chutz la’aretz* (reciting *e’eroch shu’i* on the second day of the festival).

However, as already noted by [R. David Shlomo Eybeschutz](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A5) in [Levushei Serad 663](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32863&st=&pgnum=134&hilite=) the custom he found in Israel upon making *aliyah* in 1808 was to recite the same order as in *chutz la’aretz*, and he did not feel that he had the power to change their custom.

Comment: It's worth noting the Aruch Hashulchan 663  ולכאורה למה לנו לשנות? אך אין משיבין על המנהג בדבר שעל פי דין אין שום עיכוב, אם כה ואם כה. The specific order of Hoshanot piyyutim are all late minhagim and there's no right or wrong answers, so even if the current situation was set up by a bunch of chutznikim who didn't think about what they were doing when they made aliyah, it still doesn't really matter.